# Reformat float numbers using awk

Tags: bash, awk, floating-point, format

I want to match all floating point numbers in the input and replace them with floating point numbers in a different format.

Here is something I tried:

```
echo "123.45E+00 blah 678.90E+00 blah 3.1415926535897932E+0000" \
    | awk '{gsub(/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\E\+[0-9]+/,sprintf("%E","&")); print $0}'
```

Unfortunately, the `"&"` in the sprintf is a string and not a number so the result is:

```
0.000000E+00 blah 0.000000E+00 blah 0.000000E+00
```

That's the numeric format I want but the use of `"&"` is resulting in zero as the value of the parameter, rather than the matched number.

Changing the `"%E"` format to `"%s"` works in that the original string is returned.

The output I'm wanting for the above input is:

```
1.234500E+02 blah 6.789000E+02 blah 3.141593E+00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
echo "123.45E+00 blah 678.90E+00 blah 3.1415926535897932E+0000" |
  awk '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      sub(/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\E\+[0-9]+/, sprintf("%.6E", $i), $i)
  }1'
```

Comment: @kanaka `awk` has the following structure `condition{block}`. If the condition is true then the block of code is executed. If no block is provided `awk` will executed the default block `{print $0}`. The trailing 1 is an `awk` idiom to execute the default block.

Comment: @sudo_O, interesting, thanks. I've never seen that idiom before. I don't see that obviously referenced in the man page either.

Comment: @kanaka No problem. You may find [**this**](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/) page interesting

Comment: @sudo_O, oh, I see, it's force the return condition to be true so that the default action happens.